Pyplot axis formatting issues
I'm wanting to rescale my y-axis so that it goes in even steps of two degrees. I have managed to do this with my x-axis fine. There are 54 data points. The first image is the output when the plt.ytics... line is commented out the second is when it is not. How am i meant to do this so that my graph makes sense, every tutorial i have found states that this is how its supposed to be done.
y-axis is too cluttered and doesn't need to be so precise:

Clearly incorrectly formatted y-axis:

code below
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

file = "2024-03-05.csv"
folder = "DailyData/"
filepath = folder + file
temps = []
times = []
humidity = []
tick = []

with open(filepath, newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

data = np.array(data)
data = data[2:]

for i in range(len(data)):
    times = np.append(times, data[i][0])
    temps = np.append(temps,data[i][1])
    humidity = np.append(humidity, data[i][2])

stepSize = 2
tmin = int((float(min(temps))//stepSize)*stepSize)
tmax = int((float(max(temps))//stepSize)*stepSize + stepSize)

yax = np.arange(tmin, tmax, 2)
xax = np.arange(0, len(times), 6)

plt.plot(times,temps)
plt.ylabel("Temperature °C")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.yticks(yax)
plt.xticks(xax, rotation = 90)
plt.show()


Don't set the ticks; use a locator.

Solved it. The array temps was an arry of type string. by adding the line temps = temps.astype(float) the issue went away

users would not have been able to reproduce the problem in any event give that the data contained in the csv file was not provided.

minimal reproducible example is required.
